# TABLEAU IS CONVERTING MY UTC-TIME INTO 12 HOUR AM AND PM

Tags: datetime, tableau-api, utc, calculated-field, tableau-desktop

**Desired outcome** is UTC time retained in Tableau - aviation data therefore always need UTC.

The Excel column imported into Tableau is formatted as number and represents UTC time:

[Excel screenshot of YYMMDDHHMM in UTC or "zulu" time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBoFr.png)

**Problem:** Tableau is interpreting this as 24hr time rather than UTC:

[Tableau screenshot of tableau's conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI5MJ.png)

I think I need a calculated field but haven't been able to find a solution. Is this fix possible? Thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar with tableau. But it looks like it is correctly interpreting the first value. UTC is a time zone. It is not a format for expressing date and time. I'm not breaking any rule if I write that it is currently 20:34 UTC April 21, MMXXII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A date value (or in your case a date-time value) can be formatted for presentation in several ways, just as in Excel. Changing the format doesn’t affect the underlying value, just how it is presented.

Right click on your field, press format, choose the date format you desire from the format pane on the left margin.

If you don’t think Tableau is correctly converting your string values to date time values, then you can take control of that conversion with the DateParse() function

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the direction I needed.